# Controlling DBML EntityRef creation in DBML with multiple foreign keys

Tags: linq-to-sql, foreign-keys, autogeneratecolumn

Using Linq to SQL and the autogeneration capabilities of DBML, foreign key relationships create EntityRefs in the DBML designer file.  For example :

```
private int _USStateId;

private EntityRef<USState> _USState;
```

However, if I have the need for a table with numerous FK relationships to the same table, how can i control the autogenerated names?  For example, for a **Car** survey with three FKs into a **Ratings** table, I get

```
private int _BodyRatingId;
private int _ColorRatingId;
private int _PerformanceRatingId;
```

in my Car table with

```
private EntityRef<Rating> _Rating;
private EntityRef<Rating> _Rating1;
private EntityRef<Rating> _Rating2;
```

How can I, dynamically or other wise, control the EntityRef naming to indicate that they pertain to a particular field?

Thanks!

Comment: I just stumbled accross this question. I asked a very similar question yesterday and got an answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471330/is-there-any-way-to-control-the-names-of-properties-generated-by-the-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi
I'm not sure if the question is still valid but in case anybody needs it:

You can add a partial class to your project with the same name as your Car table and add new properties:

```
public Rating BodyRating
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Rating.Entity;
        }
    }
```