# Is there any way to control the names of properties generated by the linq-to-sql designer?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, linq-to-sql, code-generation

Say you have a schema that looks something like this

```
Foo
    FooId

Bar
    BarId
    SomeFooId // Foreign key to Foo.FooId
    AnotherFooId // Foreign key to Foo.FooId
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
Bar bar = ...
DoSomethingWith(bar.SomeFoo);
DoSomethingElseWith(bar.AnotherFoo);
```

However, instead of generating `SomeFoo` and `AnotherFoo` properties, the linq-to-sql designer generates `Foo` and `Foo1`. It is not obvious which of `Foo` and `Foo1` refers to `SomeFoo`, and which refers to `AnotherFoo`. Is there any way to manually specify a name for these properties, so that I can refer to them as `SomeFoo` and `AnotherFoo`?

I am using the dbml designer in Visual Studio 2010, and I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: So when you look at your dbml file you see the correct names, but when you look in your .designer.cs and look at the partial class generated you see something different than the column name?

Comment: @esastincy: No, the names for properties directly corresponding to column names are correct. There are `SomeFooId` and `AnotherFooId` properties. But I want `SomeFoo` and `AnotherFoo` (the actual item, not the id). This works if you only have one item that is a foreign key to `Foo` (i.e., if you had `SomeFooId` but not `AnotherFooId`). But once you have multiple foreign keys to the same table, the property names become confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the names in the Linq to SQL designer.  Just click on the field you want to rename, press <kbd>F4</kbd>, and change the `Name` Property.

Alternatively, you can click on the field you want to rename, and just start typing the new name.

---

So you want to modify the names of the "convenience properties" that are generated for the foreign keys.

**EDIT**:

I figured it out.  In the LINQ to SQL designer click on the association (the line connecting the two associated tables together), expand the "Parent Property" tree and change the `Name` Property.  This will affect the generated name of the "convenience property".

Comment: See my comment reply to esastincy's comment. This works if I want to rename a property directly corresponding to a column in the database, but Linq to Sql also generates convenience properties like `Thing` when is a column `ThingId` that is a foreign key.

Comment: Thanks. That's the way I'm currently doing it, but it's not entirely adequate. The main reasons for this are: 1. I still have to rely on `Item1`, `Item2`, etc. remaining consistent each time the code is re-generated. 2. Say the code-generator created properties named `Item`, `Item1`, and `Item2`. Now I can't use `Item`, because it is already taken by the generated code. But it's better than nothing.

Comment: @Matthew, see my edit again.  I figured out how to change the name of those properties.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. Also note that if you want to change the name of the property corresponding to the inverse relationship, expand the "Child Property" tree instead of the "Parent Property" tree.